# docker is not detecting window handle to search and select file

Tags: python, docker, selenium, headless, window-handles

I am working on a selenium project with python. There is one feature of file upload, when we click on the select file button, a window handle appears where we can select the file to upload. Since selenium cannot identify windows UI element to work with window handle I have created a method which uses pyAutoit library to search and select the file. The script is working fine when working on the local machine. However, when I am trying to run the same script in headless mode on Docker, it seems the window handle doesn't appear and while running on docker. It keeps on waiting for the window handle.

```
def handle_browse_dialog(self, doc_address):
   autoit.win_wait_active("Open") #the program gets stuck on this line
   time.sleep(2)
   autoit.control_send("Open", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", doc_address)
   time.sleep(2)
   autoit.control_click("Open", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
   autoit.win_close("Open")
```

Apart from pyautoit library, I tried other libraries like (pyautogui, win32com) to work with windows handle but facing the same issue mentioned above.

docker_compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    #container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome1:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  chrome2:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:latest
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Comment: could you post your docker config ?

Comment: @Shabari_Nath_K I am using docker-compose file.